# Node JS - load and modify SVG file

Tags: node.js, svg

I'm completely new to Node JS and I want to show an SVG map. I've tried loading it as an HTML object, but it doesn't work and even if it did, I want to modify the map based on certain variables (more specifically color countries based on a query).

Edit: I tried showing the SVG by loading an html file containing the following line:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg">Nope.</object>
```

The SVG did not show in the browser.

And regarding the changes in the SVG, I know how to change the SVG, just not how to do it through JavaScript/NodeJS (I am completely new to them).

Comment: you should explain your request with much more details... this is not clear... You CAN display any svg into html page. And you can edit it with JS + html attributes on the svg objects (paths, lines, rects, etc...)

Comment: to fill a path (your country object), you should just add : fill="#FF0000" or something to your country path...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I added some details in the original question. The bottom line is that I am a noob concerning JS/NodeJS so that might explain the poorly formulated question.

Comment: I never did this through node.js, but I already did this kind of job through pure javascript.

Answer (score -1):

I never used Node.js, but I already worked on .svg files with Javascript.

Anyway, your code cannot display any svg this way, you should just display it like any html object on your page, like this :

```
...//html code
<div id="svgContainer">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g>
            <path class="country" id="Spain" d="..." fill="none"></path>
            <path class="country" id="Italy" d="..." fill="none"></path>
            <path class="country" id="England" d="..." fill="none"></path>
            <path class="country" id="Netherlands" d="..." fill="none"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
...//html code
```

For example.

Now, you wish to edit the style of a svg object (here your country) on event.
Just add your event listener on your concerned object, and edit the style.

```
element.addEventListener("click",function(){
    //Do your change stuff here
    //elementCountry is the svg "path" corresponding to a country
    elementCountry.setAttribute("fill","#FF0000");
});
```

this will fill the concerned "country" in red

You should check this : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

and this : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to update the whole map based on an array of values. How do I address the individual `id`?

Comment: The code is pretty basic. I have two parallel arrays 

`names=["Andorra", ... "Zimbabwe"]` 

and another one 

`colors=["#00cc00", ... "#ffffff"]`. I want something like 

`if(svgElementId==names[i]) svgElementFill=colors[i]`. Is that possible?